# Unable to compile assembly code with xmmword operand-size using nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm, sse, 128-bit

I was trying to compile an assembly code using `nasm` (`nasm -o file input.asm`) and threw an error at line 2 in the following code snippet:

```
mov rsi, 0x400200
movdqu xmm0,xmmword [rsi]
nop
```

I am not sure if instructions with 128 bit registers can be compiled using `nasm` but is there any other way to compile using nasm in such cases where 128 bit registers are involved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You don't need to specify an operand size** for the memory operand,
just **use `movdqu xmm0, [rsi]`** and let xmm0 imply 128-bit operand-size.
NASM supports SSE/AVX/AVX-512 instructions.

If you did want to specify an operand-size, the name for 128-bit is `oword`, according to `ndisasm` if you assemble that instruction and then disassemble the resulting machine code.  oword = oct-word = 8x 2-byte words = 16 bytes.

- [What are the sizes of tword, oword and yword operands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063840/what-are-the-sizes-of-tword-oword-and-yword-operands)
- [What comes after QWORD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645078/what-comes-after-qword)

---

Note that GNU `.intel_syntax noprefix` (as used by `objdump -drwC -Mintel`) *will* use `xmmword ptr`, unlike NASM.

If you really want to use xmmword, `%define xmmword oword` at the top of your file.

The operand-size is *always* implied by the mnemonic and / or other register operands for all SSE/AVX/AVX-512 instructions; I can't think of any instructions where you need to specify `qword` vs. `oword` vs. `yword` or anything, the way you do with `movsx eax, byte [rdi]` vs. `word [rdi]`.  Often it's the same size as the register, but there are exceptions with some shuffle / insert / extract instructions.  For example:

- SSE2 `pinsrw xmm0, [rdi], 3` loads a `word` and merges it into bytes 6 and 7 of xmm0.
- SSE2 `movq [rdi], xmm0` stores the qword low half
- SSE1 `movhps [rdi], xmm0` stores the high qword
- AVX1 `vextractf128 [rdi], ymm0, 1` does a 128-bit store of the high half
- AVX2 `vpmovzxbw ymm0, [rdi]` does packed byte->word zero extension from a 128-bit memory source operand
- AVX-512F [`vpmovdb [rdi]{k1}, zmm2`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovdb:vpmovsdb:vpmovusdb) narrows dword to byte elements (with truncation; other versions do saturation) and does a 128-bit store, with masking at byte granularity.  (One of the only ways to do byte-granularity masking without AVX-512BW, other than legacy-SSE `maskmovdqu` which has cache-evicting NT semantics.  So I guess that makes it especially interesting for Xeon Phi KNL.)

You *could* specify `oword` on any of those to make sure the size of the memory access is what you think it is.  (i.e. to have NASM check it for you.)

Comment: This explains and solves my problem. Thank you very much for the additional explanation as well.